# error al subir un laravel al hosting

Tags: laravel

[image: iimagen][imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOFBc.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOFBc.jpg)Por que en local me funciona todo bien y cuando subo mi proyecto laravel al hosting me da el siguiente error:

> Class 'App\category' not found (View:

Todo esta igual no se que cambiar

Gracias!

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Ademas por lo que parece tu código de error esta cortado.

Comment: Pregunto ¿Es un shared hosting?, De ser así subiste la carpeta Vendor?

Comment: hola!! sii es un shared hosting y subi la carpeta vendor

Comment: Probaria a ejecutar por consola el comando "composer update" y luego hacer un "php artisan cache:clear"

Comment: no tengo consola. la busco en cpanel y no me aparece :(

Answer (score 0):

Para subir un proyecto Laravel en un hosting tienes que tener en cuenta la estructura de directorios del hosting. 
La carpeta de Laravel tendría que ir en la raíz del hosting, y que el contenido de la carpeta /public de Laravel tendría que ir en la carpeta publica del hosting (public_html).
Para definir en Laravel donde esta el contenido de la carpeta /public se hace modificando el archivo /app/provaiders/appservicesproviader.php

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
        return'carpeta_publica_del_hosting';
    });
}
```

Comment: si asi es como lo tengo :( pero no funciona